# How can I communicate with a 3G modem via pySerial while it is connected?

Tags: modem, 3g, pyserial, ppp

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and a ZTE 3G modem.

The modem is dialed with [`WvDial`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/x314.html)

When the modem is not in use by `WvDial` I can send AT commands to the modem, and get information like signal strength:

```
AT+ZCSQ
+ZCSQ: 1,  -87 

OK
```

But when `WvDial` is using the modem, `/dev/ttyUSB0` is locked and I can't query it. Am I missing something obvious? Is there any way I can configure the modem, `WvDial`, or pyserial 
 so I can send AT commands to the modem while it's connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah. Apparently this modem exposes a couple of ttys to work with. I was able to use `/dev/ttyUSB1` to sent AT commands while `WvDial` was connected on `/dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600, timeout=2)

at_command = 'AT+ZCSQ\r\n'
ser.write(at_command)
ser.sendBreak()

line = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
ser.close

print line
```

Comment: Interesting, but what if there is only a single TTY? In this case, Wvdial probably has to be stopped.